# liblz4-java*.so files generated in directory other than the one specified by java.io.tmpdir

Tags: java, shared-libraries, lib, redisson, lz4

We are using [redisson-3.11.3](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) in tomcat webapp which has dependency to [lz4-java](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java) (version 1.4.0) as following:
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/redisson-3.11.3/redisson/src/main/java/org/redisson/codec/LZ4Codec.java

The tomcat\bin\service.bat has -Djava.io.tmpdir=\tomcat\temp which seems to be getting cleared when the tomcat is restarted.

We observe that lots of (21k+ files occupying 3.2+ GB) liblz4-java*.so files are getting generated in c:\windows\temp (and in c:\Users<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp in another machine)

1. Is this due to lz4-java version 1.4.0 and due to the code mentioned above?
2. Will this be cleaned up if lz4-java version 1.7.1 is used? The [commit](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java/commit/08b3bff3491eafd5238c5adf79113e56f6821e82#diff-55edf4985bef07338c2d2056e4274d9d) seems to be clearing files from java.io.tmpdir but in our machine the files are generated in directories other than java.io.tmpdir.
3. How to identify which code is generating these files?
4. How to reproduce the issue? Merely using the library does NOT seem to leave the residual files.
5. What is the ideal way to fix this?

Note:
Asked the question to github community but haven't got any response yet: https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java/issues/165 .